# Multiple conditional statements

Tags: c++, c, if-statement

I'd like to know how mulitple conditions are handled in C/C++. I have some code which works fine, but I'm concerned there is an elemtent of luck involved and I don't want to get caught out. Consider:

```
if ( (/*condition1*/) || (/*condition containing invalid reference*/) )
{
    // do something
}
```

So long as 'condition 1' is TRUE, the second condition does not appear to generate an error even though the condition by itself would produce a fault. For example:

```
int main()
{
    char    string1[] = "StackOverflow";
    char    *string2 = 0;

    // (1) This will work because string1 is valid
    if (strlen(string1) != 0)
        printf("%s", string1);

    // (2) This will cause an error
    if (strlen(string2) != 0)
        printf("%s", string2);

    // (3) But this if(OR) works fine
    if ((strlen(string1) != 0)||(strlen(string2) != 0))
        printf("no problem!");

    // (4) And of course this doesn't
    if ((strlen(string2) != 0)||(strlen(string1) != 0))
        printf("I don't believe it!");

    return 0;
}
```

It can be seen with an list of OR conditions, the if() 'question' halts at the first TRUE statement, read left to right, no matter what follows. However, changing number (3) to:

```
if ((strlen(string1) == 0) && (strlen(string2) == 0)
```

will still fail despite the first condition being false, thus rendering the whole thing as false - i.e. the question doesn't halt like the OR example.

To generalise, I have observed the following:

```
if ( (TRUE) or (INVALID) )   -> no problem

if ( (FALSE) or (INVALID) )  -> error

if ( (TRUE) and (INVALID) )  -> error

if ( (FALSE) and (INVALID) ) -> error    // see the EDIT
```

Are these results going to be universal in all cases, or is it compiler/platform dependent?

Can I get away with writing code following the above rules, or should I NEVER get into the situation where one of the conditions is invalid?

I'm going through some old code for my boss and it's littered with examples like (3) above. It will take quite some time to catch them all and adapt the code to avoid any invalid conditions. While (3) and (4) could be easily adjusted to sit inside an `if(string2 != 0) { // }` block, it's not so easy in practice for the code I have.

EDIT:

Since checking again, the `if ( (FALSE) and (INVALID) )` does indeed run without error. I don't know why it was failing before; I might not even have posed the question had it worked initially. I'll put it down to witchcraft and poor concentration.

Ultimately, while the answer has been hinted at but not confirmed verbatim, it seems this reliance on Short-Circuit Evaluation (thanks for the wiki link!) is a legitimate technique. I'm glad I don't have to re-write any code!

Comment: It's called [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: `if ( (FALSE) and (INVALID) ) -> error` isn't true, that evaluates to false without evaluating the second condition. Unless you typo'ed and used `&` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is well known behavior and it works in any C/C++ compiler that follows standard. As Jesse already mentioned in his comment that's called short-circuit and used pretty often especially with pointers:

```
void func( int *ptr )
{
   if( ptr && *ptr ) {
      // pointer is valid and integer that it points to is not 0
   }
}
```

Your last statement:

```
if ( (FALSE) and (INVALID) ) -> error
```

Is incorrect thow. and aka && will not evaluate right operand if left is false.

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about is called "short circuiting" and it is a universal feature in c++. The way it works is (TRUE || anything ) is always going to be true so the expression is not further evaluated once it knows it will be true. The same applies (FALSE && anything), because this will always be false.

a good example of how this is useful:

```
int x = 0;
cin >> x;
if (x != 0 && 10 / x == 2) {
    // ...
}
```

With this check on x, if the user enters 0, 10 / 0 will not occur, thus saving your program from dividing by 0.

You can always rely on this feature with expressions involving && and ||

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (strlen(string2) != 0)
    printf("%s", string2);
```

here `string2` is not a string so the `strlen` call invokes undefined behavior.

```
if ((strlen(string1) != 0)||(strlen(string2) != 0))
```

In C, `||` operator is guaranteed to not evaluate its right operand if its left operand evaluates to `1`. And here the left operand of `||` evaluates to `1` so `strlen(string2)`, which is undefined behavior,  is never called.

Answer (score 0):

In both C and C++ it stop evaluating boolean expressions as soon as it is sure of it result, a || operator thus always stop evaluating as soon something returns true, with the left portion taking precedence, the && stops as soon something returns false.

You can put whatever you want on the right side, that it won't evaluate.

Only keep in mind, that you used as "invalid" expression something with undefined behavior, if it ever works, there are no way to know what will happen.